# How to align theorem cases with table?

Tags: theorems

apologies if this is already answered somewhere, but I can't seem to find it (or how to ask the question properly).

I have a theorem with several cases. In each case I'd like to align my assumptions with the case label like so (from FeatherWeight Java)

[image]

However, I can only get the Case label and a table aligned from the center like so...

[image]

Is there a nice way to align the top of the table with the case label? Or is this the wrong approach? Thanks for you help, much appreciated.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath} %xrightarrow
\usepackage{amssymb} %leadsto rightsquigarrow rhd mathbb Join Subset
\usepackage{amsthm} %proof // llncs is not happy
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newtheoremstyle{custom}
{\topsep}   % Space above
{\topsep}   % Space below
{}          % Body font
{0pt}       % Indent amount (empty value is the same as 0pt)
{\itshape}  % Theorem head font
{}          % Punctuation after theorem head
{5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt} % Space after theorem head
{\thmname{#1} \thmnote{#3}} % Theorem head spec

\theoremstyle{custom}
\newtheorem*{case}{Case}

\begin{document}

\begin{case}[T-New] 
\begin{tabular}{>{$}l<{$} >{$}l<{$} >{$}l<{$}}
e = \tau_1 & \tau = \tau_2 & \\
e = \tau_2 & \tau = \tau_3 & \tau_4 \\
e = \tau_5 & & \\
\end{tabular}\\
Trivial.
\end{case}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Add the option `[t]`to tabular.

Comment: Thanks @Bernard. Couldn't have asked for a simpler answer.

Comment: @Bernard an answer? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tabular environment can take an optional argument  for its vertical alignment w.r.t. the surroundfing text: `t` (top), `c` (centred) or `b` (bottom). Use `[t]` instead of the default `[c]`:

[image]